# How to create a custom string JNDI binding in JBoss AS7?

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, custom-binding, jboss7.x

I'm looking to create a custom string JNDI binding in JBoss AS7, but can't quite figure out how to configure it.  I looked in the standalone-preview.xml file, but do not see any examples that would enable me to understand how I can configure a JNDI lookup with a simple string (URL) as a return value.   I tried looking through the docs, but do not see anything there either.

I found the following snippet on [Jboss Forums](https://community.jboss.org/message/644991#644991), but I do not understand how to use it at all.  I cannot find any documentation on `object-factory` - how to define the object-factory and/or even what it is or how it works (ie: which attributes must be set, what they  mean, etc):

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1">
    <bindings>
        <object-factory name="java:/custom/dog" module="org.jboss.animalshelter" class="org.jboss.animalshelter.resource.DogFactory"/>
    </bindings>
</subsystem>
```

I know how this was accomplished in JBoss AS6, but I cannot seem to understand how to do this for AS7.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: I guess [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212343/jboss-binding-values-into-jndi-in-jboss-eap-6-similar-to-jndibindingservicemgr) will answer to this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a [ObjectFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/spi/ObjectFactory.html). You may find for information in [Writing an Object Factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/objects/factory/interface.html).