# JBoss: Binding values into JNDI in JBoss EAP 6 similar to JNDIBindingServiceMgr

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jndi, jboss-eap-6

1. How do I bind an arbitrary string to JNDI in JBoss EAP 6? I used to
   do it through org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr MBean in
   previous EAP version.
2. Is there anything similar to org.jboss.naming.JNDIBindingServiceMgr
   in JBoss EAP 6?
3. We are migrating applications from jboss-5.1.EAP to jboss-eap-6.1.
   We need to bind some things into JNDI, so applications can look up
   values of environment variables.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.2">
  <bindings>
    <simple name="java:global/user" value="newUser"/>                
  </bindings>
</subsystem>
```

and in spring context:

```
<bean class="java.util.Properties">
  <constructor-arg>
    <map>
      <entry key="user">
         <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:global/user" />
      </entry>
    </map>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: @adi pfft, I gave the same answer an hour before this one, not fair :P

Comment: If you wanted to check the target namespace `urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.2` xsd you could see https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/tree/master/naming/src/main/resources/schema

Answer (score 2):

In your app configuration you can have things in ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor like

```
<javaee:env-entry>
    <javaee:description>JNDI logging context for this app</javaee:description>
    <javaee:env-entry-name>logback/context-name</javaee:env-entry-name>
    <javaee:env-entry-type>java.lang.String</javaee:env-entry-type>
    <javaee:env-entry-value>our-app-context</javaee:env-entry-value>
</javaee:env-entry>
```

or, if you prefer to have it in the server standalone.xml, do

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1">
    <bindings>
        <simple name="my/jndi/key" value="MyJndiValue"/>
    </bindings>
</subsystem>
```

the latter (standalone.xml) is a JBoss 7.1 feature, so available in EAP 6.0. In JBoss AS 7.0, a dummy application needs to be used according to [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/message/615368).

Answer (score 0):

What if simply:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
ctx.bind("varName", "value");
```

If you use that code inside of a JBoss instance you can bind variables into jndi. Remember to use the correct format for varName to bind the variable in the desired scope.

Comment: I am looking for a JBoss configration example... r. adding the java properties in standalone.xml