# how to configure @localbinding and @remoteBinding in wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly-8, ejb-3.2

We are migrating from JBOSS6 to wildfly8.2 and as wildfly support EJB3.2 and EJB3.2 does not support @LocalBinding / @RemoteBinding ,so how will I do the same in wildfly using standalone.xml / ejb-jar.xml / any other configuration.

I tried [JBoss: Binding values into JNDI in JBoss EAP 6 similar to JNDIBindingServiceMgr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212343/jboss-binding-values-into-jndi-in-jboss-eap-6-similar-to-jndibindingservicemgr) thread but could not link where i will map the jndi name to my EJB and how lookup will be happened.

Please help. 
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This information provided into wildfly documents, can be used by others also as I am going to test with it to implement for my question:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JNDI+Reference